# we started getting the below error after we bumped the flink version from 1.15 to 1.17

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have upgraded to flink 1.17 from 1.15. After upgrading the job, we are facing exceptions which are causing the job to fail. We are using fixed-delay restart strategy and the job is deployed on kubernetes cluster.

1.

```
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Fatal error occurred in TaskExecutor akka.tcp://flink@100.126.185.4:6122/user/rpc/taskmanager_0.
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: The TaskExecutor's registration at the ResourceManager akka.tcp://flink@100.126.2.182:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_0 has been rejected: Rejected TaskExecutor registration at the ResourceManager because: The ResourceManager does not recognize this TaskExecutor.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor$ResourceManagerRegistrationListener.onRegistrationRejection(TaskExecutor.java:2442) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor$ResourceManagerRegistrationListener.onRegistrationRejection(TaskExecutor.java:2386) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutorToResourceManagerConnection.onRegistrationRejection(TaskExecutorToResourceManagerConnection.java:109) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutorToResourceManagerConnection.onRegistrationRejection(TaskExecutorToResourceManagerConnection.java:40) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.registration.RegisteredRpcConnection.lambda$createNewRegistration$0(RegisteredRpcConnection.java:269) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRunAsync$4(AkkaRpcActor.java:453) ~[flink-rpc-akka_cc24e6b4-98f0-431f-98c7-e598a837bc44.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68) ~[flink-rpc-akka_cc24e6b4-98f0-431f-98c7-e598a837bc44.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRunAsync(AkkaRpcActor.java:453) ~[flink-rpc-akka_cc24e6b4-98f0-431f-98c7-e598a837bc44.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:218) ~[flink-rpc-akka_cc24e6b4-98f0-431f-98c7-e598a837bc44.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:168) ~[flink-rpc-akka_cc24e6b4-98f0-431f-98c7-e598a837bc44.jar:1.17.0]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24) [flink-rpc-akka_cc24e6b4-98f0-431f-98c7-e598a837bc44.jar:1.17.0]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20) [flink-rpc-akka_cc24e6b4-98f0-431f-98c7-e598a837bc44.jar:1.17.0]
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:127) [flink-rpc-akka_cc24e6b4-98f0-431f-98c7-e598a837bc44.jar:1.17.0]
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:126) [flink-rpc-akka_cc24e6b4-98f0-431f-98c7-e598a837bc44.jar:1.17.0]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20) [flink-rpc-akka_cc24e6b4-98f0-431f-98c7-e598a837bc44.jar:1.17.0]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:175) [flink-rpc-akka_cc24e6b4-98f0-431f-98c7-e598a837bc44.jar:1.17.0]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176) [flink-rpc-akka_cc24e6b4-98f0-431f-98c7-e598a837bc44.jar:1.17.0]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176) [flink-rpc-akka_cc24e6b4-98f0-431f-98c7-e598a837bc44.jar:1.17.0]
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537) [flink-rpc-akka_cc24e6b4-98f0-431f-98c7-e598a837bc44.jar:1.17.0]
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535) [flink-rpc-akka_cc24e6b4-98f0-431f-98c7-e598a837bc44.jar:1.17.0]
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220) [flink-rpc-akka_cc24e6b4-98f0-431f-98c7-e598a837bc44.jar:1.17.0]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:579) [flink-rpc-akka_cc24e6b4-98f0-431f-98c7-e598a837bc44.jar:1.17.0]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:547) [flink-rpc-akka_cc24e6b4-98f0-431f-98c7-e598a837bc44.jar:1.17.0]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270) [flink-rpc-akka_cc24e6b4-98f0-431f-98c7-e598a837bc44.jar:1.17.0]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231) [flink-rpc-akka_cc24e6b4-98f0-431f-98c7-e598a837bc44.jar:1.17.0]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243) [flink-rpc-akka_cc24e6b4-98f0-431f-98c7-e598a837bc44.jar:1.17.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
```

2. 

```
Remote connection to [null] failed with java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

Comment: Looking at the actual error code in the Flink source, this usually is thrown when you have multiple TaskManagers/JobManagers running on the same machine with different Flink versions. Can you verify that you have no old versions still running after the upgrade?

Comment: @MartijnVisser We made sure that multiple flink versions are NOT running on same machine. But, still the jobs are failing with the same exception.